# jQuery .hover on Android - Prevent clickthrough

Tags: android, jquery

The following code works fine to display a dropdown on the desktop, and on iOS, but on Android, it creates a click event and refreshes the page. How can i stop that? I've not found anything simple to solve this?

jQuery:

```
$('nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeIn(100);

    }, 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeOut(100);         
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I don't known it is possible. The reason is simple how can you differ a hover, a long push on a smartphone or a tap ? Maybe firefox on Android implements it but I'm not sure. After my training on this subject I can see it was better to developp an android application or develop another site for this devices.

Answer (score 0):

This will be because it translates the hover into a tap. You have no page to load in the code about so a # will be amended to your URL showing the link was successful.

Comment: I think i have it figured out, going to answer in a second.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way to do this or not, but this prevents the page from refreshing in Android while still using the hover code to show the dropdowns (which are simply ul children of nav ul li.

```
$('nav li').hover(
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeIn(100);
    }, 
    function () {
        $('ul', this).fadeOut(100); 
    }
);

$('nav a[href=""]').click(function(){
    return false;
});
```